# Form with multiple gridviews, select only one item from only one grid. Other grids must unselect rows/loose focus as we change selection within grids

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have a winform with 3 gridviews. I want to focus on one row in one grid at any given time. If i select select row from second gridview, others grids if they have any selcted rows must be unselected and loose focus. How can I acheive this?

Comment: I haven't used DevExpress GridView before, but with a little search it looks like you could just [call `ClearSelection`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ClearSelectiontopic) on the two non-active GridViews.

Comment: I tried using that but for some it's not working as expected and also it works only when 'MultiSelect = true'. I want that to work event if we change 'MultiSelect =false'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. The Grid focused row is synchronized with the current position in CurrencyManager which always has a row focused. I suggest you take a look at the [Is it possible to set up the grid to have no focused row?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A902) article at DevExpress. It describes this and provides a way to make the Grid **look** like it does not have a focused row.

Comment: I have an issue with this approach. If I have 3 grids A, B and C. When I select nth(any) row in A and then select any row in B, grid A looses focus but when I again select the same nth row in A it does not get focus. This happens with all the grids.